# How to understand "of longing the discovery of the broken mirror had occasioned" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

> Then he placed the fragment on top of that morning's Daily Prophet, which lay unread on the bed, and attempted to stem the sudden upsurge of bitter memories, the stabs of regret and **of longing the discovery of the broken mirror had occasioned,** by attacking the rest of the rubbish in the trunk.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I don't quite understand "of longing the discovery of the broken mirror had occasioned". According to dictionaries, 'occasion' is a transitive verb, meaning "***to cause***", but here it's used as an intransitive verb and the sense "to cause" doesn't seem to fit. So, I'm confused.

What's the phrase "*of longing the discovery of the broken mirror had occasioned*" modifying, "the stabs" or "the sudden upsurge"?

And what does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

> Then he ... attempted to stem the sudden upsurge of bitter memories, the
> stabs of regret and of longing the discovery of the broken mirror had
> occasioned ...

**Paraphrase**

Then he ... attempted to stem  
(a) the sudden upsurge of bitter memories, 
(b) the stabs of regret and 
(c) [the stabs] of longing, 
**that** the discovery of the broken mirror had occasioned ...

*Then he ... attempted to stem the sudden upsurge of bitter memories, the stabs of regret and of longing, that the discovery of the broken mirror had occasioned ...*

Answer (score 0):

*...to stem the sudden upsurge of bitter memories, the stabs of regret and of longing* (that) *the discovery of the broken mirror had occasioned.*

*The discovery of the broken mirror **had occasioned** the longing.*

Comment: Certainly, but more detail would not go amiss.  Perhaps explain the grammar structures involved?

Comment: Why is there no definite article preceding 'longing'? *the longing (that) the discovery of the broken mirror had occasioned*

Comment: @Andrew     Alas, that's beyond me. If somebody post a fuller answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @dan It's actually *the discovery of the broken mirror had occasioned the stabs **of regret and of longing***; i.e., *the stabs of regret and the stabs of longing*.

Comment: The word "that" really should have been included, for clarity if nothing else.  The answer is correct.  He is not "longing the discovery".  He is having "stabs of regret and of longing" which were caused by the discovery.